# Cython with python 3.3

Tags: python, cython

I have been using python 3.3

This is an old problem as I searched, and this is what I did:

helloworld.pyx

```
print("Hello world!")
```

Then, in ipython, I did:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import helloworld
```

It says:

> ImportError: Building module helloworld failed: ["ValueError:
>   ['path']\n"]

The same problem did not happen with python 2.7

I googled this: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows
and realized that I have to install Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4. As it comes with the VC++2010 Redistributables, I did not install the redistributables alone again. I thought I had everything ready, but the import error still remains.

Could anyone please help me solve it?

Thank you!

-Shawn

Comment: Do you really need pyximport?  It seems the error messages might be more intuitive if you build an extension module as a separate step, and then import it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install Windows 7 SDK, then open cmd run:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x64

then run:
python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the same environment (win7 64bit, python-3.3.3 64bit).

I have

1. installed the Windows 7 SDK as described on the wiki [cython wiki](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows) as you did,
2. applied the patch (`msvccompiler9_33.diff`) from this [python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue7511),
3. fixed the above patch by defining a missing variable as described [here](http://bugs.python.org/msg196929)
4. Installed MS Visual C++ Express 2010 (seems to be required)
5. Updated the Windows 7 SDK to include the "Windows Headers and Libraries", "Tools" and of course the "Visual C++ Compilers" the MSVC++2010 redistributable.

And now I can compile and import the `helloworld.py` just fine.